# First run of Rails on Windows: ERROR ArgumentError: dump format error for symbol(0x6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm taking my first tentative steps with Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to get it up and running on a Windows machine (Win7 64). I installed using RubyInstaller and then installed Rails using Gem.

I've had a bit of a nightmare because of missing gems, having to install devkit etc. which has been great fun for someone who has no idea what they're doing.

Anyway, I've finally got to a point where I can run a new "empty" rails project and I was hoping to see the default rails page.

Unfortunately instead I get an Internal Server Error and the following in the log:

```
[2011-11-16 10:30:56] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-11-16 10:30:56] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]
[2011-11-16 10:30:56] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3432 port=3000
[2011-11-16 10:31:19] ERROR ArgumentError: dump format error for symbol(0x6)
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_view/template.rb:24:in `load'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_view/template.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.1/lib/coffee/rails/template_handler.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_view/base.rb:216:in `<class:Base>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_view/base.rb:133:in `<module:ActionView>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_view/base.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb:90:in `view_paths='
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb:76:in `prepend_view_path'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:532:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:234:in `<class:Base>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:171:in `<module:ActionController>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:31:in `ext'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:15:in `match?'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:47:in `call'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2.rc2/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

The line throwing the error is "conversions = Marshal.load(File.read(filename))" in the following code block:

```
if defined?(RUBY_ENGINE) && RUBY_ENGINE == 'ruby' && RUBY_VERSION == '1.9.3' && RUBY_PATCHLEVEL == 0
  # This is a hack to work around a bug in Ruby 1.9.3p0:
  # http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5564
  #
  # Basically, at runtime we may need to perform some encoding conversions on the templates,
  # but if the converter hasn't been loaded by Ruby beforehand (i.e. now), then it won't be
  # able to find it (due to a  bug).
  #
  # However, we don't know what conversions we may need to do a runtime. So we load up a
  # marshal-dumped structure which contains a pre-generated list of all the possible conversions,
  # and we load all of them.
  #
  # In my testing this increased the process size by about 3.9 MB (after the conversions array
  # is GC'd) and took around 170ms to run, which seems acceptable for a workaround.
  #
  # The script to dump the conversions is: https://gist.github.com/1342729

  filename    = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'data', 'encoding_conversions.dump')
  conversions = Marshal.load(File.read(filename))
  conversions.each do |from, to_array|
    to_array.each do |to|
      Encoding::Converter.new(from, to)
    end
  end
end
```

I seem to have a hit a bit of a (WE)Brick wall, and have no idea where to go from here (except maybe a Linux VM).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

LJ

Comment: I just deleted that bit of code and it sort-of works now - well I got further. So far it's taken me a day and I haven't even managed to get the "hello world" example to run.

Comment: A *nix VM would be a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  It's a firewall issue.  Goto to Start>Allow a prgram through Windows Firewall. Make sure that Home/work(Private) is checked for "Ruby interpreter". I was good to go after that!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same book and had the same issue, I remove Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and install Ruby 1.9.2-p290, it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Strange guys. There is a discussion on github about a similar problem, but it only happen on upgrades of rails version: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2509.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you are holding too much data in your `flash` or `session` variables in the previous request. Try to hold only ids instead of objects, for example.